# Icon/image in circle rotates with rotation of circle

Tags: javascript, html, css, geometry

I am facing a problem with circle rotation.

Problem :- I have an outer circle on which there are several circles. And in that several circles there is an image. But on the rotation of circle , the image is also rotated which I don't want. The image has to be fixed inside circle div.

```css
.circular_blue {

height: 400px;

width:400px;

-webkit-animation-name: spin_1;

-webkit-animation-duration: 40000ms;

-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;

-moz-animation-name: spin_1;

-moz-animation-duration: 40000ms;

-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

-moz-animation-timing-function: linear;

-ms-animation-name: spin_1;

-ms-animation-duration: 40000ms;

-ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

-ms-animation-timing-function: linear;

animation-name: spin_1;

animation-duration: 40000ms;

animation-iteration-count: infinite;

animation-timing-function: linear;

}

@-ms-keyframes spin_1 {

from { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); }

to { -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); }

}

@-moz-keyframes spin_1 {

from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }

to { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }

}

@-webkit-keyframes spin_1 {

from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }

to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }

}

@keyframes spin_1 {

from {

transform:rotate(0deg);

}

to {

transform:rotate(360deg);

}

}

.circular_reverse{

height: 200px;

width:200px;

position: absolute;

top: 24%;

left: 7%;

-webkit-animation-name: spin_2;

-webkit-animation-duration: 40000ms;

-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;

-moz-animation-name: spin_2;

-moz-animation-duration: 40000ms;

-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

-moz-animation-timing-function: linear;

-ms-animation-name: spin_2;

-ms-animation-duration: 40000ms;

-ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

-ms-animation-timing-function: linear;

animation-name: spin_2;

animation-duration: 40000ms;

animation-iteration-count: infinite;

animation-timing-function: linear;

}

@-ms-keyframes spin_2 {

from { -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); }

to { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); }

}

@-moz-keyframes spin_2 {

from { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }

to { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }

}

@-webkit-keyframes spin_2 {

from { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }

to { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }

}

@keyframes spin_2 {

from {

transform:rotate(360deg);

}

to {

transform:rotate(0deg);

}

}
```

```html
<div class="circular_blue">

<div style="height:400px;width:400px;border:3px dotted red;;border-radius:50%;/*! position: absolute; */">

<div style="height: 100px;width: 100px;background: #c6b7b7;border-radius: 50%;/*! display: table; */position: relative;">

<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/city/" style="height: 50px;position: absolute;z-index: 999999;top: 27%;/*! display: table-cell; *//*! vertical-align: middle; *//*! width: 50px; */left: 24%;">

</div>

</div>

</div>
```

[image: when this rotates then image is also rotates]

What I want is , When rotating outer circle, the inner circles should rotate but with no rotation of image/icon.

Any help would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you planning on rotating the largest circle with an animation? I don't see any rotated images when I run your snippet.

Comment: yes.. largest circle should rotate and along with it the inner circles should rotate but no image should rotate inside circles.

Comment: i have edited my code.. you can see that the image inside circle is also rotating with the circle.

Comment: Perfect. Give me a minute to go through it.

Comment: yes. .sure.. no worries..

Comment: Can't you just move your img element outside of the circular_blue div? It's already absolutely positioned, so as long as they're in the same relative div it should be the same no?

Comment: didn't get you.. why should i move the img div outside **circle_blue** div. I have tried but id didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "undo" the effect of the animation by running it in reverse on every image:

```
.circular_blue img {
    animation-direction: reverse;
    // other animation stuff
}
```

However, I noticed in your code that you have a ton of `-<browser>-animation-<stuff>` lines, so I thought I would mention that there is [a shorthand `-<browser>-animation` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) which allows you to set everything at once:

```css
.circular_blue img {
  -webkit-animation: 40s linear infinite reverse spin_1;
  -moz-animation: 40s linear infinite reverse spin_1;
  -ms-animation: 40s linear infinite reverse spin_1;
  animation: 40s linear infinite reverse spin_1;
}

.circular_blue {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  -webkit-animation: 40s linear infinite spin_1;
  -moz-animation: 40s linear infinite spin_1;
  -ms-animation: 40s linear infinite spin_1;
  animation: 40s linear infinite spin_1;
}

@-ms-keyframes spin_1 {
  from { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to { -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes spin_1 {
  from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin_1 {
  from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes spin_1 {
  from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="circular_blue">
  <div style="height:400px;width:400px;border:3px dotted red;;border-radius:50%;/*! position: absolute; */">
    <div style="height: 100px;width: 100px;background: #c6b7b7;border-radius: 50%;/*! display: table; */position: relative;">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/city/" style="height: 50px;position: absolute;z-index: 999999;top: 27%;/*! display: table-cell; *//*! vertical-align: middle; *//*! width: 50px; */left: 24%;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's great buddy.. but there are 2 doubts.. 1 : image div is slightly shivering and rotation is not infinite. it ends after one rotation.

Comment: The shivering is a bit of an issue, I'm going to see what I can do about that. And the infinite is an easy fix, I just have to add that into the `animation` property.

Comment: yes.. yes.. just found in my code and wrote infinite. and it's done.. thank you for your answer..